# Custom shape in android using xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-custom-drawable

I am trying to draw a custom shape which I can use as a background for my layout. But I am not able to do so. Is it possible to draw a shape as below using xml in android. I am not getting how to cut the semicircle shape from the vertical  centres of rectangle.

[image]

Comment: please be more specific about the shape. rounded corners, colors etx

Comment: take image view and set background drawable and src drawable in layout.

Comment: no, it cannot be done, use nine patch drawable instead

Answer (score 6):

Use `layer-list` to make this custom shape `drawable`.

**/res/drawable/custom_shape.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Transparent Rectangle -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
                android:topRightRadius="8dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="4dp" />

            <size
                android:width="300dp"
                android:height="100dp" />
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Left Half-Circle -->
    <item
        android:left="-10dp"
        android:right="290dp"
        android:top="40dp"
        android:bottom="40dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Right Half-Circle -->
    <item
        android:left="290dp"
        android:right="-10dp"
        android:top="40dp"
        android:bottom="40dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Middle Dotted Line -->
    <item
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp">
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:dashWidth="10px"
                android:dashGap="10px"
                android:color="#ff00"/>

        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**USE:**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_shape"/>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 1):

try bellow xml. save it in drawable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners
android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
android:topRightRadius="15dp"
android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
/>
<solid
android:color="#ffffff"
/>
<padding
android:left="0dp"
android:top="0dp"
android:right="0dp"
android:bottom="0dp"
/>

<stroke
android:width="1dp"
android:color="#000000"
/>
</shape>
```

Comment: I think it need to write two rounded rectangle shapes. One is at top and another is at bottom.

Comment: no need to write two shape. <corner> tag allow us for different radious at corners

Comment: @PrashantJajal This will create a simple rectangle with rounded corners. How to cut the two circles which are present in the left and right side centre of the rectangle?

Comment: @DhirajDevkar  it cannot be done, use nine patch drawable instead

Comment: so its better to use nine patch. @DhirajDevkar

Answer (score 1):

In your case it might be worth to create a resizable bitmap (**9-Patch** drawable). Follow [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html) guide.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use 9-Patch images. If you can create an image like above you can use https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html to create 9-patch image(define expandable area).

Answer (score 0):

Try this xml file in drawable :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape= "rectangle">
<solid android:color="@color/primary" />
<corners android:radius="50dp"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below xml, it may help you out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:top="10dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size
                android:width="200dp"
                android:height="200dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp"
                android:dashWidth="10px"
                android:dashGap="10px"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="103dp"
        android:left="-10dp"
        android:right="205dp"
        android:top="103dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size
                android:width="3dp"
                android:height="3dp" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="103dp"
        android:left="205dp"
        android:right="-10dp"
        android:top="103dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size
                android:width="3dp"
                android:height="3dp" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: This xml looks perfect, just the way I want it. But, when I am setting the same xml as a background to my Linear Layout , the circles on the left and right side centre are not visible.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle" >

        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        <corners android:radius="3dip" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#ED2A3C" /> 
    </shape>
```